# Wants to add Scroll in Registration Page in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I tried with  NestedScrollview, CustomScrollview but not get proper output.
I want to add scroll in Registration page without taking list .
I added data as a TextFormField. 
parent is Container and inside Container add Scfold as a child.
Here is my code:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  SingleChildScrollView in your  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//Like this: 
 return SingleChildScrollView(
        child:Column(
}

Comment: Yes I added SingleChildScrollView already it works normally but I want to use it with Form widget if you used it please let me know.